# Is it possible to execut two handlers for the same command? (eclipse rcp)

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have an application and want to hook onto an existing command. But I don't want to replace any existing handlers, I want to **add** functionality (preferably after the default handler finished executing).

Is this possible? Or do I have to find another way to do this?

The scenario is this: I want to register when somebody copies stuff in Eclipse. Then I want do stuff with the things that the user has copied. Since the existing copy functionality is great I don't want to change that. But I would like to know when somebody has executed a copy command.

Note: This only needs to work inside Eclipse! ;) I don't need to monitor the clipboard outside of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a way to do this! After researching a *lot* I found this interface: [IExecutionListener](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/class-use/ExecutionEvent.html). The javadoc says:

> A listener to the execution of commands. This listener will be notified if a command is about to execute, and when that execution completes. It is not possible for the listener to prevent the execution, only to respond to it in some way.

This is *exactly* what I want: Don't interfere with the existing command but get notified when it is executed.

So here's the code to add an execution listener to the default copy command:

```
public void addListenerToCopyCommand() {
    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI
      .getWorkbench().getAdapter(ICommandService.class);
    Command defaultCopyCommand = commandService
      .getCommand(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY);
    defaultCopyCommand.addExecutionListener(new MyCopyListener());
}

public class MyCopyListener implements IExecutionListener {
        @Override
        public void preExecute(String commandId, ExecutionEvent event) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void postExecuteSuccess(String commandId, Object returnValue) {

            // !!! Do stuff with the copied things here !!!!

            System.out.println("copy command has executed");

        }

        @Override
        public void postExecuteFailure(String commandId,
                ExecutionException exception) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void notHandled(String commandId, NotHandledException exception) {
            // do nothing
        }    
}
```

All I have to do now is add an Activator for my plugin that will run when the plugin is started and voila: My Plugin is notified whenever the user copies *anything*!

Comment: Be warned that with Eclipse Lazy Loading your plugin will not be loaded unless some thing require it to be loaded (a view for example). So your activator might never be called. Have a look at the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think I'll stick with the lazy loading though. The ExecutionListener will be added when the user displays the view of my Plugin - otherwise they get "normal" copy functionality. That's fine with me. :)